# Weird output with javascript closure/scope

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

im new to javascript, I was trying to understand the closure/enclosure thing, here's some simple code:

```
var i = 10;
var g = 3;
console.log("Commencing countdown, engines on");

while ( i > 0 )
{
    console.log(i);
    i--;
    var g = 6;
}

console.log("this is g " + g );
```

When I run this I'm getting "this is g 6", but shouldn't it be 3 since that's the g from the global scope and the g = 6 is only done in an inferior scope?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: There's no block scope in JS.

Comment: @Teemu in ES6 block scope is widely available, whether you're declaring a block scoped variable using `let` or simply by wrapping a snippet in `{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The while loop does create a block scope for each iteration, however, by using `var`, you're instead defining that variable in the function scope rather than the block scope. If you instead used `let`, it would leave the outer `g` var as is.

*Note that this is only supported in modern browsers.*

```js
var i = 10;
var g = 3;
console.log("Commencing countdown, engines on");

while ( i > 0 )
{
    console.log(i); //1-10
    i--;
    let g = 6;
}

console.log("this is g " + g ); // 3
```

Your original code gets parsed as this:

```
var i = 10;
var g = 3;
console.log("Commencing countdown, engines on");

while ( i > 0 )
{
    console.log(i); // 1-10
    i--;
    g = 6; // var was hoisted, so now this is setting the value of `g` in the function scope rather than the block scope.
}

console.log("this is g " + g ); // 6
```

Which of course has the outcome you saw.

Answer (score 5):

javascript has function scope not block scope(unless you use `let`). so,

```
while ( i > 0 )
{
    console.log(i);
    i--;
    var g = 6;
}
```

so `g` here is not a new variable but just the global variable.